using react query to send value to server and cant get new values in my component
import { apiRequest } from './apiRequest';

export async function createEditItem(data, id) {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/pos';
    const requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    if (!id) {
        try {
            const res = await apiRequest(
                `${apiUrl}/item`,
                'POST',
                requestHeaders,
                data
            );
            return res;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}

import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { createEditItem } from '../../api/item';
import { apiRequest } from '../../api/apiRequest';
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useCreateItem () {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const {
        isLoading,
        mutate: createItem,
        error,
        data,
    } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: createEditItem,
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(['Item']);
            console.log(data);
        },
        onError: (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        },
    });

    return { data, isLoading, error, createItem};
}

import { useCreateItem } from './useCreateItem';

export default function FormComponent() {
    const { createItem, data: dataItem} = useCreateItem();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dataItem) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));
        }
    }, [dataItem]);

    async function onSubmit (data){

        dataNewItem = 'value2';
        await createItem(dataNewItem);

        if(!dataItem) return;
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));
        data.newItem = dataItem;
    }

    return (
        <Form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}
        >
            ...form element
            <button type='submit'>Send Item to server !</button>
            .....
        </Form>
    );
}

when i onSubmit my form i call createItem. this createItem will send 'value2' to server to insert into DB and then if success give it back the 'value2' and with new id to the client.
i can see the success of this process when i see this line of code in my hook and in my useEffect. i can see the 'value2' with new id.
   onSuccess: (data) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['Item']);
      console.log(data);
    },

and this too
 useEffect(() => {
     if (dataItem) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));
   }
 }, [dataItem]);

the problem is why i cant get the new value ('value2'). i cant get directly the new value and this code below will return old value the 'value1'
   console.log(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));
   data.newItem = dataItem;

